# How to continuously re-run the Puppet agent with a 65-second pause interval with countdown between each two runs

Tags: bash, puppet

The goal is to have the `puppet agent -t --debug --verbose` to be continuously re-run while allowing for pause intervals of 65 seconds (with countdown) between each two runs.

Please note that {{cron}} and {{watch}} could not be used because the pause intervals start from the end of the previous {{puppet agnet}} run.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
puppet agent -t --debug --verbose; while time_seconds=$((65)); while [ $time_seconds -gt 0 ]; do echo -ne "$time_seconds\033[K\r"; sleep 1; : $((time_seconds--)); done; do puppet agent -t --debug --verbose; done
```